# Deserializing json array with JSON .net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json string that looks like this:

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "name": "20200809/1",
      "fields": {
        "details": {
          "stringValue": "bad"
        },
        "paid": {
          "stringValue": "yes"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "20200809/4",
      "fields": {
        "details": {
          "stringValue": "good"
        },
        "paid": {
          "stringValue": "no"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

the strings that matter for me are `name`, `details` and `paid`. When I retrieve the information from the server, it comes like this json.

I'm using JSON .net (`JsonConvert`) to deserialize but I think I'm doing it wrong. How can I get `name` and `details` from this json?

```
List<object> json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(jsonString);
Dictionary<string, object> dict = json[0] as Dictionary<string, object>;
//get name
string name = dict["name"] as string;
```

It gives me:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: an array starts with `[`and an object starts with `{` - guess what you have here

Comment: You can read the docs for [JSON Path](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm)

Comment: So the beginning object is a `Dictionary<string, List<object>>` instead?

Comment: Somehow ... but that would not be very helpful. Try it to "feel" what is bad about it. If you do not want to build a class structure for that json then use JSON Path

Comment: Feel free to post the use of `JObject` as answer and I'll gladly accept it. Just solved the problem using it :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    string jsonString = "{'documents':[{'name':'20200809/1','fields':{'details':{'stringValue':'bad'},'paid':{'stringValue':'yes'}}},{'name':'20200809/4','fields':{'details':{'stringValue':'good'},'paid':{'stringValue':'no'}}}]}";
//Note: You must convert to JObject
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
//Note: And get documents object get zero index and "name" key and fixed!
var jsonMemberName = jsonObject["documents"][0]["name"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The complete object represented by your JSON is a `Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary>>` - you will have to parse the whole structure and use a map/collect loop to get the specific keys that you need, or can use `JSON Path`